# How to change toolbar title with fragment back stack

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have made a very simple application with multiple fragments in one activity. Also, added toolbar.

Now 4 fragments have different titles.

when I go to fragment 1 the title is **Fragment 1**

when I go to fragment 2 the title is **Fragment 2**

now come to the problem....

when I press back from fragment 2,

I came to fragment 1.

but the title in the toolbar is still **Fragment 2**

This is the problem I want to solve.

Please help me to fix this.

Explain me in easy steps (prefer java)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using navigation component?

Comment: no i am not using that

Comment: I found there are alot of ways but the ways I found are checking which Fragment is currently displayed in Activity, then change accordingly. Another way is create a method in Activity which changes the title and call it in your fragment. First one is better I think

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by using an `OnBackStackChangedListener` in your `Activity`:

```
supportFragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener {
    val fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.yourFragmentFrame)
    if (fragment is BaseFragment) {
        header.text = fragment.header()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one Toolbar for each Fragment. it's an easy way to set the header.

Just you need show each Fragment full in Activity layout.

you can create one toolbar XML and include it into each Fragment XML Layout.

see the [Single Activity](https://oozou.com/blog/reasons-to-use-android-single-activity-architecture-with-navigation-component-36)